# SQL - Complicated lookup query

Tags: sql, performance, lookup-tables

I need help with a complicated query. I have a `Venues` table, a `Tag` table and a `Venues_Tag_lookup` table. When I have the detail of a single venue on screen I would like to be able to show other venues that are similar to the current venue.

This will require a query that returns the top 5 venues with the most amount of matching tags. (I'm using MSSQL)

Here is a simple layout of how my tables look.

```
Venues_tbl
----------
VenueId
Venue_name

Tag_tbl
---------
TagId
Tag_name

Venues_Tag_lookup
------------------
Venue_tagId
VenueId
TagId
```

If you have any question please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said `"most amount of matching tags"`. You are matching tags with what?

Comment: Hi Talha, The idea would be that if 'venue A' had five tags, the query should return any other venues that have any of 'venue A''s tags. Ideally returning them in order of venue thaat have the most matching tags. (so a venue that has 3 fo the 5 tags would be ordered before a venue that has 2 of the 5 tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 5
   V.Venue_name
FROM
   -- this = tags for this venue
   Venues_Tag_lookup this
   JOIN
   -- others = tags for other venues
   Venues_Tag_lookup others
            --see what matches, there will be a big pile of them
            ON this.TagId = others.TagId
   JOIN
   Venues_tbl V ON others.VenueID = V.VenueID
WHERE
   --filter to this and others
   this.VenueID = @TheOneOnScreen
   AND
   others.VenueID <> @TheOneOnScreen
GROUP BY
   --collapse to other venues ...
   V.Venue_name
ORDER BY
   -- ... and simply COUNT matches
   COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Wow, This is spot on. Thank you very much. If you have time could you please explain to me what the WHERE clause is doing. I think that the only part on not sure about.

Comment: The WHERE clause is separating the 2 Venues_Tag_lookup reads. One for "this venue" and the other "not this venue"

Answer (score -1):

following query may help:

```
-- params = @venueId, @tagId

select
        venueId,
        venueName,
        (select count * from venues_tag_lookup vtl where vtl.venueid=v.venueid )tagCount
from venues_tbl v
where venueId in(
  select venueId from Venues_tag_lookup where tagId = @tagId
)
and venueId  @venueId
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: This will show "one tag for one venue". Not "matching tags for other venues"